Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:upgrader/upgrader.dart'

I attempted to use the upgrader package in Flutter. Despite restarting the IDE and changing the version, I encountered the following issue:

"Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:upgrader/upgrader.dart'."

Steps I've taken to resolve the issue:


Restarted the IDE.
Changed the package version.
Pub get

pubspec.yaml
name: 
description: 
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+2

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^1.1.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.12
  provider: ^6.0.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.0
  intl: ^0.18.1
  nepali_utils: ^3.0.3
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.0
  firebase_core: ^2.21.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.3
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  rive: ^0.12.3
  lottie: ^2.7.0
  badges: ^3.1.2
  dependency_validator: ^3.2.3
  googleapis_auth: ^1.6.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.2
  overlay_support: ^2.1.0
  upgrader: 

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/app_icon/icon.jpg"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/animations/

  fonts:
    - family: roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf
        - asset: fonts/roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf


Can you share your pubspec.yaml file? Also, which IDE are you using?

@tomerpacific I am using AndroidStudio. Also I create a new file to see if it was the package issue. But it worked on the other file but not on my main flutter file.

Where is this file located?

I mean a new flutter project.

Can other packages in my pubspec.yaml cause this issue?

Why aren't you giving a version to upgrader inside your pubspec.yaml file?

I did that but I dont think that matters. When leaving empty doesn't it provide current updated version automatically?
